# Print data from two different tables with a shared field (mysql and php)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to bring data from two different tables where there is a shared field:
in table1, I have many fields and one of them is the employee **Position** which is a number. 
in table2 I have two fields: **EmpPos**(which is equal to **Position** in table1) and **PosName**.
Now, I want to print all employees' info from table1 but instead of printing **Position**(which is a number), I want to print its associated **PosName** from table2.
My following query is not working!

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.Position=table2.EmpPos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Position Name</th>
        <th>phoneExt</th>

    </tr>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['table1.FirstName'] ." " .$row['table1.LastName'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['table1.Email'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['table2.PosName'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['table1.phoneExt'] ."</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you didn't define any relationship between the tables. So you should be using INNER or LEFT JOIN for this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 m INNER JOIN
Table2 k ON k.EmpPos = m.Position
```

Or the following should do:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 m LEFT JOIN
Table2 k ON k.EmpPos = m.Position
```

As you have a foreign key (Shared field), then it's easy and obvious to use joins.

Comment: do you mean that I have to define a foreign key in the database?, because I tried your code and it gives this error: (Undefined index: table1.FirstName) and the same for all fields

Comment: I can see, there is already a foreign key defined. In both the tables, you have a field positionId. Change the table names and columns according to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Using Inner JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM table1 tab1 INNER JOIN table2 tab2 ON tab1.position = tab2.EmpPos
```